# Funcion getchar() lee solo la primera letra

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
FILE *fd;
void agregar(int nombre_articulo, char direccion[]);
int main()
{
    int respuesta, c;
    int nombre_articulo;
    char direccion[] = "C:\\Users\\ploo\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\datos_inventario\\pelis.txt";

    while(respuesta!=3)
    {
        printf("\n\tINVENTARIO\n1.Revisar inventario\n2.Agregar articulo\n3.Salir\n");
        scanf("%i", &respuesta);
        switch(respuesta)
        {
            case 1:
                fd=fopen(direccion,"rt");
                if(fd==NULL)
                {
                    printf("ERROR");
                    return 1;
                }
                while((c=fgetc(fd))!=EOF){
                    if (c=='\n')
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        putchar(c);
                    };
            } fclose(fd);break;

            case 2:
                agregar(nombre_articulo, direccion);break;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void agregar(int nombre_articulo, char direccion[]){
    int respuesta;
    while (respuesta !=2)
    {

        while((nombre_articulo = getchar()) != EOF && nombre_articulo != '\n')
        {
        printf("Cual es el nombre del articulo que se desea agregar?\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEs %s el nombre correcto?\n", &nombre_articulo);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n1.Si\t\t\t2.No\n");
        scanf("%i", &respuesta);
        if (respuesta== 1)
        {
            fd=fopen(direccion, "wt");
            if (fd==NULL){
                printf("ERROR");
            }
            fprintf(fd,"\n");
            fwrite(nombre_articulo,1,strlen(nombre_articulo),fd);
            respuesta = 2;
            fclose(fd);

        }
    }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que el nombre de la función es suficientemente obvio. `getchar` **solo lee un caracter**. Si leyese una cadena lo lógico sería entonces que tuviese un nombre tipo `getstring` o `getline` o similar.

Para leer una cadena **no necesitas** un `int` sino un array de `char`:

```
int nombre_articulo; // <<--- Quita esto
char cadena[100]; // Por ejemplo
```

Y, en segundo, lugar, necesitas usar una función que lea cadenas de texto:

```
scanf("%s",cadena); // Si no quieres leer espacios

getline(cadena, 100, stdin); // Si quieres leer la linea entera
```